# Mac: markdown file, could not edit

Tags: mac, markdown

I have some markdown files, usually I can edit them easily and totally.

This time there are some `.md` file which I could not click and open.

Show a image:

[image: one]

The `.md` file , which could not be edited, has different color, it is light gray.

I had changed its mode to 777, readable and writable . While it is not working.

Here is the summary of one `.md` file, which could not be edited

[image]

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a guess, partly because I can't read most of it, but I'd say those files are incomplete copies, on their way, or failed to be fully written from another location.

One big clue is that the created date of any file whilst in transition is 24th January 1984 [the date of the famous [Apple "1984" Super Bowl advert]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984_(advertisement))
The other, of course, is that they're greyed out, & that the file size shows as 0 KB.